# Import local package in Go code inside GOPATH?

Tags: import, go

Is there any way in Go to do a local import (such as `"./package1"` or `"../package2"`) in a package that's in your GOPATH? Local imports work outside of your GOPATH, but when they're from a package in GOPATH, the compiler complains. Any way around this? It seems like an annoying restriction that prevents code mobility since moving a package or renaming it requires renaming all of the imports to packages that still maintain the same relative structure, but have also moved.

Comment: No, sorry, no longer. (Renaming is dead simple, so why bother?)

Comment: Just seems needlessly brittle to me. What's the harm in allowing local imports? Do you know the reasoning on this?

Comment: The reasons are technical. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/1XqcS8DuaNc/x8HAasCF_LUJ and https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/_usbgS9LeS8/-rHbJuu8nXwJ . Searching golang-{nuts,dev} for "local imports" will bring up more discussions. Most important: In practice it is not brittle but very nice.